How to use SPNEGO authentication in JBoss EAP 8.0?
We've implemented a webapp that is deployed on JBoss EAP 6.4 using SPNEGO authentication, and we are wanting to migrate our webapp to be deployed on JBoss EAP 8.0.  The security systems have changed from versions 6.4 to 8.0, and I have had trouble finding good documentation about how to use SPNEGO with 8.0.
JBoss EAP 8.0 corresponds to Wildfly 28, and I have found a Wildfly Elytron Security Guide.    In its HTTP Authentication section, it states:

The HttpAuthenticationFactory is an authentication policy for
authentication using HTTP authentication mechanisms, including the
BASIC, DIGEST, EXTERNAL, FORM, SPNEGO, and CLIENT_CERT mechanisms.

My standalone.xml file includes:
        <http-authentication-factory name="spnego-http-authentication" security-domain="SPNEGODomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
            <mechanism-configuration>
                <mechanism mechanism-name="SPNEGO" credential-security-factory="mip-mdaca-cse"/>
            </mechanism-configuration>
        </http-authentication-factory>

My web.xml specifies SPNEGO as its authentication method.
<login-config>
    <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
    <realm-name>SPNEGORealm</realm-name>
</login-config>

However, when I start JBoss, I get errors:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The required mechanism 'SPNEGO' is not available in mechanisms [BASIC, CLIENT_CERT, DIGEST, FORM] from the HttpAuthenticationFactory.
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.AuthenticationManager.initialSecurityHandler(AuthenticationManager.java:174)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.AuthenticationManager.lambda$configure$2(AuthenticationManager.java:100)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.SP3-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.setupSecurityHandlers(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:445)

Why isn't SPNEGO recognized as a valid option?  What can I do to make it work?
